# Running Flutter App in Simulator not working

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

I got to work on a Flutter App, which is going to be deployed on Android an iOS. I'm using Android Studio for this.
I'm working on a Mac and wanted to test the App on both the Android Emulator and the iOS-Simulator.
The Emulator works fine, but when I want to launch the App on the Simulator, I geht the following Error:

```
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            1,8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
            { id:334E8563-0B42-474D-9397-D6481F6C0A36 }

        Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
            { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00006020-000C49AA0C98C01E }
            { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }

Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/7z/lzrcy2t95yjb68zt5756w2s80000gn/T/flutter_tools.i7cer4/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir30Geyx/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
```

Due to some older dependencies, I'm using Flutter 3.0.0 with Dart 2.17.0.
XCode is Version 15.0 and Android Studio on Version 2022.3.1 Patch 1

To check if anything gone wrong while configuring Flutter, XCode, etc. , I created a new Flutter project and tried to run it on the Simulator, which worked perfectly fine.

I already deleted the existing devices from the Simulator and create new ones, tried it with an older version of iOS running on the simulated devices, but that also did not work.

Does anyone know, how to solve this and get the App to run on the Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue after updating Xcode to 15, you can try by update cocoapods and invalidate cache and then restart Android studio.